# The connection with the client was abnormally terminated during the network communication between the server and the client

Tags: c#, networking, server, network-programming, client

The connection with the client was abnormally terminated during the network communication between the server and the client. What should I do in this situation? I do not know which exception to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the information given is very minimal, but I would suggest you to check the followings to start with

1. Try pinging the client/server from each other and confirm network connectivity.
2. Is there a firewall causing network connection to disrupt, you may need to open some ports in that case.
3. Look into client and server log files - if at all they are there.
4. Did server process crashed? do ulimit -c unlimited before starting the process.
5. Did client process crashed? do ulimit -c unlimited before starting the process.
6. Try doing the connect/send/receive in try-catch blocks, and put proper prints in catch block. There can be a broken pipe exception.
7. I would say check the buffer size that you are sending or receiving, both client and server should be able to handle the size.
8. In case you find core files in #2 or #3, load the core and see where it is crashing, it will give you the best hint.
9. If you are on Linux, try digging out information from system logs - e.g. /var/log/messages etc., if not on Linux find equivalent files.

I can provide more details once the incidence is clear, e.g. what you are trying to send, is it happening every time or some of the times? What is the message printed in catch block?